# Passing operators as parameter to get method

Tags: jsp, get

I am using get method to send data from one page to another page. I want to send c++ as a parameter. What i tried is simply wrote c++ like this:

```
<a href="assessments.jsp?testname=c++">C++</a>
```

But i received 'c' only on the assessments.jsp page, when i wrote this statement:

```
String test_name=request.getParameter("Test_Name");
```

I know '+' symbol is passed as %2b in address, but i don't know about other symbols. How can i pass c++ so that i can obtain same on next page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>
<%
    String value = URLEncoder.encode("C++", "UTF-8");
%>
<a href="assessments.jsp?testname=<%=value%>">C++</a>
```

But, you should use JSTL and the c:url and c:param tags

Answer (score 0):

use jstl `<c:url>`,

```
<a href="<c:url value="assessments.jsp">
    <c:param name="testname" value="c++"></c:param>
  </c:url>">C++</a>
```